# Which international credit card would fit my requirements?

Tags: canada, credit-card, international, australia

I am currently looking at getting a credit card for myself.  However, as per [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/global-credit-record-would-my-good-credit-history-apply-internationally), I would like to get a credit card from an international bank / credit provider so that when I move countries I still have some credit history.

My credit needs aren't too high at the moment - the credit card would most likely just replace a Visa Debit card - but I don't know what companies are out there that will provide me with good service in Australia (where I currently live) and Canada (where I plan to move).

Which (international) credit providers would be able to provide me with a credit card that fits these requirements?  My preference would be for Visa / MasterCard, but if there are others that are also suitable, I am happy to consider them.

Comment: @MrChrister - I mentioned that it was Canada in my question

Comment: I have a rare form of dyslexia that prevents me from seeing the names commonwealth nations in writing.  Sorry.

Comment: Related question http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/global-credit-record-would-my-good-credit-history-apply-internationally/2983#2983

Comment: @gerdemb - that's already linked in this question

Answer (score 1):

Your credit history will not move internationally; However, having a provider who is willing to consider your "internal" credit history in one country when opening accounts in another country is still very useful.

I know American Express does this - I got a US Amex purely on the conduct of my UK Amex, albeit with approx 50% of the limit of the UK card (which is still plenty for my needs).

I also believe that HSBC offers some sort of international bank account moves but I got fairly conflicting advice in the UK if regular account holders qualify for that. Their 'premier' customers do, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Australia doesn't have a positive credit rating system - only a negative system. This means that you'll only have a rating if you've not paid or defaulted somehow on your debts.

In addition, credit scores include the number of enquiries. Too many enquiries can reduce the credit score you receive as it may look like you're being turned down for credit and are hunting for a more lenient lender.  Having no enquiries may count against your credit score if  you're 40 as it would be unusual that you've never had a credit card, utility or mobile phone account.

So, within Australia at least, getting a credit card can not improve your credit score, but will increment the number of enquiries.